# Can you change your flair on the site?

Tags: support

Is it possible to change your flair on the site or is it just to do it on others? The blank one is kinda boring.

Answer (score 5):

No, we do not have any option to modify the appearance of flair on the site as it appears on your posts.

Comment: We have flair? I'm confused.

Comment: @Fluttershy Go to your profile and in the upper right, in between "preferences" and "apps" is the "flair" option. It's an HTML snippet you can use on any site to show off your network rep/info. For example, yours is [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/14775/fluttershy/flair).

Comment: RIP HTML (rather than image based) flair.